# How to obtain with a RRN a version of a temporal XOR function using keras/tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, rnn, mlp

I'm trying to implement a model of a recurrent neural network to solve a temporal version of the XOR problem, but I am not still able to do that. Any hints?

Comment: It is customary to solve it using `MLPs`. `XOR` does not have any temporal behavior at least as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to add in the question that I need to use a recurrent neural network

Comment: What is the temporal component of the problem? Without that, there is really no reason at all to use RNNs. The person who gave you the task should be made aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following [this link](https://gist.github.com/stewartpark/187895beb89f0a1b3a54) helps you, I have gone trough those tutorials previously.
Also take a look at [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/recurrent-neural-network-algorithms-for-deep-learning/) .

Comment: Thank you. They are very useful. I use them. I forget to add in my question that I need to use recurrent neural networks

Comment: Tq.Accept it if you found it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
import keras
import numpy as np



a = np.array([[1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]])
b = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = (2, )))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(), metrics = ['accuracy'], loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(x = a, y = b, epochs = 750)
```

If you don't get `100%` accuracy increase the number of epochs. Also take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/26642/28175) which may help you how increasing the size of each layer affects the learning process.

Comment: Thank you. I used that example. I forget to add in the question that I need to use recurrent networks. I try to do this: https://github.com/katejarne/xor_recurrent_test but I cant make my code works:

Comment: I solved the problem a couple of years ago. I implemented such a function. I forgot that I have posted the question and published 2 papers on Computational neuroscience. Here are the links to the paper, each of them has the repository: https://doi.org/10.1007/s11571-022-09802-5 and https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2632-072X/abdee3  Also on my GitHub is more: https://github.com/katejarne/RRN_dynamics

Comment: @Cecilia sorry for my late late response. I'm really happy that finally you did it :)