# Neural Network beginner level tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a simple multi layer perceptron Neural Network in Java, but apparently my calculations are off. I am looking for a beginner-level tutorial which can help me to understand how to properly calculate forward and backward pass, preferably with examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the number of neurons and layers in neural networks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26597/how-to-set-the-number-of-neurons-and-layers-in-neural-networks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of articles which helped me a lot is : [A Step by Step Backpropagation Example](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/) by **Matt Mazur**. It covers forward and backward pass of MLP. I hope that helps.

Another great source is http://www.deeplearningbook.org/

Answer (score 0):

Apart the mentioned resources, this also might be of help: [MLP Java example](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs9417ml/MLP2/). It's from the University of Sydney and includes theory and a Java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial [Neural Network: A Complete Beginners Guide from Scratch](https://medium.com/gadictos/neural-network-a-complete-beginners-guide-from-scratch-cf1fc9d5cd12?source=friends_link&sk=caecf88153c2ffa029fb322ca40c6adc). It's covered the very basics and also shared the code.