# Predict method of the perceptron algorithm

Tags: python, perceptron

Can someone explain to me how the predict method of the perceptron algorithm works?

```
def predict(self, pattern):
    activation = np.dot(self.w, pattern) + self.b
    if activation > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

In this example b stands for bias.

```
def train(self, pattern, label, step = 0.01):
    out_label = self.predict(pattern)
    if out_label == label:
        return True
    self.w += step * (label - out_label) * pattern
    self.b += step * (label - out_label)
    return False
```

This is the train method. But as far as I understand in out_label there will only be either 1 or -1. How could this be possibly equal to label? If we would return activation I (think) I would understand it.

Comment: The weights specify a line, 1 and -1 represents whether the point is on each side of the line.

Comment: Okay, I revisited now the entire code. But aren't the weights like 0.something values?How do they represent a line?

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/26642/28175). About the weights, do you know about decision boundary? I guess the link may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the code appears to break down:

**method parameters:**

The `train(...)` method takes an input vector called `pattern` along with the target output called `label` and a weight update coefficient (learning rate) called `step`.

---

**method execution:**

1. `train(...)` first passes the input vector through our neuron using the `predict(...)` method.
2. The result of `predict(...)` is stored in a variable named `out_label`.
3. The `out_label` variable is either `1` or `-1`.
4. Depending on the pattern that we provide we want the target output (`label`) to be either `1` or `-1`.
5. If `out_label` is equal to `label` (`1 == 1` or `-1 == -1`), then we return `True`
6. Otherwise, the neuron outputted a value we do not want (`-1 != 1` or `1 != -1`), so we update the weights accordingly, then return `False`

---

**example where the neuron is *correct*:**

Let's say we have the following parameters:

input vector (`pattern`) = `[-5,2,8]`

target output (`label`) = `1`

The `train(...)` method executes as follows:

1. we call the `predict(...)` which does the following:

   - passes our vector `[-5,2,8]` through the neuron using the function `np.dot(self.w, pattern) + self.b`
   - stores the result of the above function in a variable called `activation` (let's say `activation = 0.23`)
   - returns `1` because `activation > 0`
2. we store the result of `predict(...)` in the variable `out_label`, which is `1` in this example
3. because our target output (`label = 1`), is equal to the actual output (`out_label = 1`) of the neuron, we return `True` and consider the neuron output correct.

---

**example where the neuron is *incorrect*:**

Let's say we have the following parameters:

input vector (`pattern`) = `[-1,-5,3]`

target output (`label`) = `1`

The `train(...)` method executes as follows:

1. we call the `predict(...)` which does the following:

   - passes our vector `[-1,-5,3]` through the neuron using the function `np.dot(self.w, pattern) + self.b`
   - stores the result of the above function in a variable called `activation` (let's say `activation = -0.65`)
   - returns `-1` because `activation <= 0`
2. we store the result of `predict(...)` in the variable `out_label`, which is `-1` in this example
3. because our target output (`label = 1`), is *not* equal to the actual output (`out_label = -1`) of the neuron, we update the weights using:
   `self.w += step * (label - out_label) * pattern
   self.b += step * (label - out_label)`
4. we then return `False` because the neuron was incorrect