# Retraining Neural Network with Optimal Number of Layers/Neurons

Tags: neural-network

So let's say you have determined the optimal number of layers/neurons for your neural network. When it comes time to re-train your network with new data values (the inputs are the same, just newer data for the inputs), would the optimal number of layers/neurons need to be determined again, or would the previous numbers be sufficient for re-training?

I do not have formal training in neural networks and I don't have a background in statistics, but from the answers in the post [How to set the number of neurons and layers in neural networks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26597/how-to-set-the-number-of-neurons-and-layers-in-neural-networks) I get the strong indication layers/neurons describe the complexity of the relationships between the inputs/outputs and I can surmise that as long as those relationships hold in the new data, determining the optimal layers/neurons is not needed before re-training, but I'd like some more experienced opinions or facts.