# How to implement keras LSTM time series

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am learning how to implement Keras `LSTM` on a simple time series data. 
The dataset I'm using has $12$ columns and $300k$ rows. Each group of $200$ rows represents one time-series cycle. Then, the time starts again from zero and run for the next $200$ rows. I want to make predictions for sixof the columns. 
My questions are, how many (multiple of 200?) rows do I choose for train/test sets? Is my batch size $200$? What is the basis for choosing number of neurons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not provided the dataset but I will try to answer based on your descriptions.

> how many (multiple of 200?) rows do I choose for train/test sets?

Actually, the train/validation/test splits do not really depend on the length of the time series. It is more dependent on the number of examples, time series here. $300k / 200 = 1.5k$ which means the size of your dataset is small and you can use the customary percentages for your splits. Something like 60/20/20 for train/validation/test.

> Is my batch size 200?

$200$ is not your batch size, it is the length of your signal. In `LSTM` networks, you usually deal with temporal data. For each sample, you have 12 features for each time step. $200$ means each sample has $200$ steps. In vectorise implementations of `LSTMs` it is customary to define batch size. That is, you stack $m = batch size$ samples for acceleration in training, it has details that I skip.

> What is the basis for choosing number of neurons?

Take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/26642/28175). Although the details of `MLPs` are described, they can be generalised to `LSTMs` too. Consider `RNNs` like simple `MLPs` which take the inputs of the current time step and the outputs of the previous step.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. Please see the edit above.

Comment: @MatN  I guess you are not very familiar to the concepts. First take a look at [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537).

Comment: Thank you, Media. But this helps me very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc