# What is the structure of a MLP that allows for arbitrary decision boundaries?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm just doing some reacher for my machine learning class, I found out it must be three layers MLP. But why? Is there a proof/paper or I'm wrong?

Comment: Make your question more precise. Give the exact statement that is the source of your confusion.

Comment: Please provide more context for the question.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26597/how-to-set-the-number-of-neurons-and-layers-in-neural-networks/26642#26642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that the fact that MLP allows for arbitrary decision boundaries derives from the fact that an MLP is a universal approximator.

The theoretical area addressing the capability of neural networks to be able to approximate any function are the different flavors of the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem), for which there are two directions: the arbitrary width case (which you refer to when you assume that the ability comes from the three layers), and the arbitrary depth case.

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) page contains the mathematical formulation of both directions, as well as reference to their respective proof for different assumptions.