# Handle Unbalanced data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, class-imbalance

I have a data-set with 2 target classes.
In training dataset, the ratio of the 2 classes are 1:93

With my neural network, the current accuracy is 63%.
I tried undersampling, oversampling, equal sampling but not improvements.

Comment: try to change your architecture, also use F1 score for evaluation.

Comment: change architecture? as in change the number of hidden layers or manipulating the data

Comment: is F1 score for evaluation in keras available directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified that what neural network you are using but as comments, you should try to fit your data first. You have to try to find a model that learns your training data. For this purpose you don't have to increase the number of data, at least not at this stage. You should try to find a good model which suits your data. For this purpose you have to change the hyper-parameters of your neural network, e.g. number of layers or number of neurons in layers. You can take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/26642/28175) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/26291/28175) which the former can help you and the latter helps you understand the features learned by `CNNs` in case you are using them.

For using `F1` score in `Keras` I've not seen but you can implement it and pass it to compile method, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45411902/5120235).

Comment: I am using a standard neural network of 4 layers(20,30,10,2). Isn't CNN used when with more layers we can detail out the features?

Comment: I guess you are using `MLP`. We use `CNNs` usually in cases that the locality of the features, like images, are important. If you have image data I recommend you using `CNNs`. Moreover both links may help you. Also, welcome to our comunity.

Comment: yes, i am using mlps. your links were really helpful