# what is filter and kernel_size?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

For below line of code

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)))
```

Here, what does 'filers' and 'kernel_size' mean? or what is filter and kernel_size ?

Comment: Please refer older answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831038/trouble-understanding-convolutional-neural-network

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do convolutional neural networks work?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15903/why-do-convolutional-neural-networks-work)

Answer (score 3):

Filters are used to extract features from images in the process of convolution.

> filters: Integer, the dimensionality of the output space (i.e. the
>   number of output filters in the convolution).
>
> kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of 2 integers, specifying the
>   height and width of the 2D convolution window. Can be a single integer
>   to specify the same value for all spatial dimensions.

For detailed undestadning of filter and kernel_size, refer: 
https://www.saama.com/blog/different-kinds-convolutional-filters/ 
https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/